# ExtJs loading nested JSON data MVC

Tags: json, extjs, extjs-mvc

I know this has been discussed a lot of times, but I just can't get my code working...
So I have a PHP script which returns the following JSON.

I want the data to be loaded in a grid like this:

name | status | ztn | dtn | idn

```
{
   "success":true,
   "code":0,
   "message":"works",
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"connection1",
         "status":1,
         "locks":[
            {
               "ztn":"abc",
               "dtn":"def",
               "idn":"123"
            },
            {
               "ztn":"ghi",
               "dtn":"jkl",
               "idn":"456"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"connection2",
         "status":1,
         "locks":[
            {
               "ztn":"mno",
               "dtn":"pqr",
               "idn":"789"
            }
         ]
      }
```

My store is set up like this:

```
Ext.define('VPN.store.Connections', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    id: 'connectionStore',
    requires: [
        'VPN.model.Connection',
        'VPN.model.ConnectionLocks'
    ],
    model: "VPN.model.Connection",
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'api/router.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

My first model looks like this:

```
Ext.define("VPN.model.Connection", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    id: 'connectionModel',
    fields: ['name', 'status'],
    hasMany: {
        model: 'VPN.model.ConnectionLocks',
        name: 'locks'
    }
});
```

and my second model like this:

```
Ext.define("VPN.model.ConnectionLocks", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    id: 'connectionLocksModel',
    fields: ['ztn', 'dtn', 'idn'],
    belongsTo: 'VPN.model.Connections'
});
```

The grid's store is `VPN.model.Connections`. `name` and `status` are displayed correctly, but the lock's `ztn`, `dtn` and `idn` are not shown...
So where's my mistake?

Comment: You can query the resulting nested `store` on each `Connection` item like so `store.data.items[0].locks()`.  Does this not return the proper `ConnectionLocks` store items for the `Connection` item?

Comment: I'm pretty new to ExtJS and especially MVC. so where do I have to run that? I always get `store is undefined` or `Cannot call method 'locks' of undefined`...

Comment: You need to find the corresponding parent store. Here is an example all inline: `Ext.getStore('Connections').data.items[0].locks()`

Comment: through the console I saw, that it returned the proper `ConnectionLocks`. But how can I load them into my grid? For example which `dataIndex` do I have to use?

Comment: Well, there is a one to many relationship between the stores.  So displaying them in the current grid would be difficult.  There are examples online of adding an expander to the grid to relay data. Or sometimes, i'll just add a second grid to display the child store.

Comment: The problem is, that the `lock's` are data reffering to a specific name, so I can't just create another grid... Isn't there a way of parsing them or such through a column renderer or so?

Comment: I usually change the subsequent grid on the selection change (only showing the corresponding items for the selected item).  I see you found a work around to aggregate the data, cool.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround. It's a part of a snippet I found and changed.
I replaced the `dataIndex` in my `store`-definition with the following code

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
                values = [];
                record.locks().each(function(lock) {
                    values.push(lock.get('idn'));
                });
                return values.join(', ');
            }
```